# UML: specifying the mapping of a class attribute to a database table column?

Tags: uml

I am trying to find a way of specifying how a given class attribute is persisted to an existing database model that I cannot modify at the moment. What i need to convey in a UML class diagram is how a class attribute is mapped to a given table column. Should I use stereotypes for this as illustrated below or is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should definitely not use stereotypes.

A stereotype denotes a meta-class that is an extension of a UML meta-class.
**«table»** is a commonly used stereotype used as an extension of the UML Class to indicate that this object is to be interpreted as a table rather then a generic Class.

Stereotypes can also define properties who will manifest in the model as tagged values. As such you could imagine a «column» stereotype that has a property **mapping** in which you can add a reference to the class attribute(s).

Some UML tools also have some sort of feature to link attributes to other attributes. UML doesn't really specify how this should be represented in a diagram, so the tools each have their own notation.
Enterprise Architect for example uses this notation:

[image]
(from the user manual)